# Ajax - Load content into Textarea

Tags: php, javascript

I have this simple ajax code, for some reason it wont load content onto textarea. I need it to load the content so that it can be edited in the textarea.

Here's the code, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. But it displays in a div like so

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Here's the full code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Editing Page Content</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showCustomer(str)
{
var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?file="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Page Select to edit</p>      

        <?php  

             $result = mysql_query("SELECT pagename FROM site_content");            
                echo "<select name=\"pagename\" onchange=\"showCustomer(this.value)\" style=\"width:300px;\">";             
                echo "<option selected  value=''>Please select a page to edit...</option>";             
                 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
                 echo "<option selected value='" . $row['pagename'] ."'>" . $row['pagename'] . "</option>\n";           
               }            
             echo "</select>";          

             ?>     

            <div id="content">
                 **it works here**
             </div>

            <textarea cols="50" id="area1" style="position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 300px;">
                     **It won't work here**
            </textarea>  

            <input type="button" value="Submit content">  

            </div>     
        </body>             
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use jquery it's awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code this looks to do exactly what you want:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Since your `div` has the id of "content" the response is being put there.  Try something like:

```
document.getElementById("area1").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

---

I must also advise you to take a look at the [PHP documentation on choosing a MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) as `mysql_*` is considered outdated and is in a long-term deprecation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You probably misunderstood it, the content display when it's ordinary div, but not in textarea. If I change the 'content' ID to that of the textarea, it does not display there.

Comment: @HelenNeely Are you changing the property from `innerHTML` to `value`?

Comment: Thanks that worked. Infact, I think part of the problem might be with the nicEdit html editor I'm using. It doesn't seem to refresh the textarea content. :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
document.getElementById("area1").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```